# Average minimum distance between two random vectors

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $\mathbf{y_1} =\begin{bmatrix}g_1x_1 & g_2x_1 & \dots & g_Nx_1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{y_2} = \begin{bmatrix} f_1x_2 & f_2x_2 & \dots & f_Nx_2\end{bmatrix}$. All the elements of $\mathbf{g}=\begin{bmatrix} g_1&g_2 &\dots &g_N\end{bmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{f}= \begin{bmatrix} f_1 & f_2 & \dots & f_N\end{bmatrix}$ are drawn from a rayleigh distribution. $x_1$ and $x_2$ are taken randomly from the set $\{-1,1\}$ with equal probability, i.e, $x_1$ can be $1$ or $-1$ with $0.5$ probability and similaraly $x_2$. There are four combinations for $(x_1, x_2)$: $(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)$ which will lead to four combinations for $(\mathbf{y_1}, \mathbf{y_2})$ as well. Define $d$ as the euclidean distance between $\mathbf{y_1} \text{and } \mathbf{y_2}$: $d=\mathbf{|y_1-y_2|}$. I would like to calculate the probability density function of $d_\min = \min(d)$. I need the distribution because my goal is to calculate the average minimum distance $E(d_\min)$. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are unlikely to be able to get a closed form expression for this. Even in $\mathbb{R}^1$ you would clearly need a closed form expression for the PDF of the sum of two Rayleigh RVs, which is not known. There are however good approximations http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1388722&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fiel5%2F4234%2F30221%2F01388722.pdf%3Farnumber%3D1388722

Comment: @KaiSikorski Thanks for the paper.

Comment: @KaiSikorski If you calculate the distance, you end up with a sum of $\it square$ of Rayleigh rvs. I think the square of Rayleigh RV is exponential. So I'd probably end up with a sum of exponential rather than Rayleigh.

Comment: No you get the square of the sum

Comment: @KaiSikorski I see. but I think you get the square of the difference not the sum, i.e for a given $x_1, x_2$ you get $(g_1x_1-f_1x_2)^2$

Comment: Yeah it depends on $x_1$ and $x_2$. In the $(1,-1)$ case it would be the sum. I was saying that determining the distribution of the sum of Rayleigh is one of the questions you would have to determine; you are correct that the difference would also come in in the $(1,1)$ case for the $x$s for example.

Comment: If you're interested in the case where the number of dimensions is large though what you should do is just computer the mean and variance of $(g_1 x_1 - f_1 x_2)^2$ which (probably?) should have a closed form solution. Then given that the number of dimensions is large and they are all independent you can apply the central limit theorem. This should give a good approximation.

Comment: @KaiSikorski Thanks for the good suggestion. Yes I'm interested in the case of a large $N$, so as you said I can invoke the central limit theorem.